# Setting the InputStream on a DefaultInvocationRequest when using the Maven Invoker API

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to invoke other maven plugins in interactive mode using the maven invoker API, but the interactive mode fails without an InputStream set on the InvocationRequest. Is there a way to retrieve the console prompter at this point?

```
InvocationRequest invocationRequest = new DefaultInvocationRequest();
invocationRequest.setPomFile("/some/pom/file/pom.xml");
// set up goals etc
invocationRequest.setInteractive(true);
// Here I need to add the input stream: eg invocationRequest.setInputStream(???);

Invoker invoker = new DefaultInvoker();
InvocationResult result = invoker.execute(invocationRequest);
```

Without an input stream the invoked goals can't complete.

---

EDIT [a bit of clarification]:
There's a .setInputStream method on the InvocationRequest object. The DefaultInvoker checks to see if this has been set if the request isInteractive.

```
if ( request.isInteractive() ) {
    if ( inputStream == null ) {
        getLogger().warn("Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.");
        // etc
```

This suggests that it should be possible to set the InputStream to a suitable value, but I'm not sure how to access it.

Comment: If you are using the invoker you are trying to start Maven as a whole like on command line and not only a plugin. The question is what you like to achieve?

Comment: Thanks  khmarbaise, yes I get that - I'm trying to call the release goals release:prepare and release:perform, but have to perform some validation here (and set some properties) before doing so. The idea is that we can run myplugin:release rather than having to run a custom goal and then run release. I appreciate that this could be done by binding to the lifecycle, but this isn't appropriate for what I'm doing (basically conditionally releasing subprojects according to scm change logs).

Comment: Subprojects release in a multi module does not make sense, cause it's against the idea of a multi-module idea. Apart from that what kind of validation does you need to do? May be you could enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: There's a .setInputStream method on the InvocationRequest object. The DefaultInvoker checks to see if this has been set if the request isInteractive. This suggests that it should be possible to set the InputStream to a suitable value, but I'm not sure how to access it.

Comment: As far as my project goes - yes, it is not actually a multi-module project that gets built at the same time - it is a release project that covers a whole platform. The components that constitute a release are loosely coupled, so we don't always want to release component x when we release component y. We do however want to have a platform version that includes components x, y and z in their correct / current version. The plugin I'm writing basically allows us to release components that require it without releasing everything. It programmatically replaces our current process of...

Comment: ... release components that have changed, update dependency version numbers in "platform" pom, release "platform" project.

Comment: @Tom Did you find how ?